# Adjust elements in table header to show inline

Tags: html, css, primefaces

I am having three to four elements inside 'th' of a table.

1. The header label
2. The sort icon
3. label of filter but in my case, it is hidden though present in dom
4. Input text filter or a date range selector wrapped in div.

This 'th' is auto-generated by component library primefaces, I have no control over it. The issue is when there are lots of columns the sort icon for some columns moves to a new line and the input and date range do not align.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
label1 long| label2 ^  | label3 ^         | label4 is longg |
^          | _________ | ---------------  |^                |
_________  |           | | select date |  | --------------  |
           |           |                  | | select date|  | 
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

The HTML output for above is something like

```
    <th id="entityForm:results_table:j_idt280" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-column ui-filter-column ui-state-active" role="columnheader" aria-label="Task Number: activate to sort column ascending" scope="col" tabindex="0" aria-sort="descending">

        <span class="ui-column-title">Task Number</span>

        <span class="ui-sortable-column-icon ui-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>

        <label id="entityForm:results_table:j_idt280:filter_label" for="entityForm:results_table:j_idt280:filter" class="ui-helper-hidden">Filter by Task Number</label>

        <input id="entityForm:results_table:j_idt280:filter" name="entityForm:results_table:j_idt280:filter" class="ui-column-filter ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="" autocomplete="off" aria-labelledby="entityForm:results_table:j_idt280:filter_label" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">

</th>
```

What I have done is

1. Given 'th' a position of relative
2. the first span of header label margin and 80% width.
3. The sort icon a position of absolute and offsets from right
4. The input box and date range selector I have tried to give a fixed same height and absolute position with the offset from the bottom.

With this, they align up and sort icon does not move to the new line.

I am not a UI developer, just need some ideas is this the best way to achieve this, or maybe I have overdone this.
I have to support IE 10 and above.

My Css is

```
th.ui-sortable-column.ui-filter-column {
    position: relative;
}


th.ui-sortable-column.ui-filter-column > span.ui-column-title {
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

th.ui-sortable-column.ui-filter-column > span.ui-sortable-column-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 4px;
}


th.ui-sortable-column.ui-filter-column > .ui-column-filter {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height:25px;
}


th.ui-sortable-column.ui-filter-column > .ui-column-customfilter > button.comiseo-daterangepicker-triggerbutton {
    height:25px;
}

th.ui-sortable-column.ui-filter-column > .ui-column-customfilter > button {
    bottom: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Please advice.